# Zabbix server not starting listener failed: zbx_tcp_listen() fatal error: unable to serve on any address [[-]:10051]

Tags: zabbix

Error in logs

```
listener failed: zbx_tcp_listen() fatal error: unable to serve on any address [[-]:10051]

[root@abc-zabserver-b zabbix]# netstat -lntp | grep 10051
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10051               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2150/zabbix_server
tcp        0      0 :::10051                    :::*                        LISTEN      2150/zabbix_server
```

Service status and when trying to start

```
[root@abc-zabserver-b zabbix]# service zabbix-server status
zabbix_server is stopped
[root@abc-zabserver-b zabbix]# service zabbix-server start
Starting Zabbix server:                                    [  OK  ]
[root@abc-zabserver-b zabbix]# service zabbix-server status
zabbix_server is stopped
```

Process is running (sometimes shows multiple processes running)

```
[root@abc-zabserver-b zabbix]# ps afx | grep -i zabbix
 3852 pts/1    S+     0:00  |       \_ grep -i zabbix
 2150 ?        S      0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
```

But service still stopped

```
[root@abc-zabserver-b zabbix]# service zabbix-server status
zabbix_server is stopped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying Zabbix with puppet and I had

```
ensure => installed (instead of specific version)
```

What this did is install a newer version of Zabbix whereas the config file I sourced was still from an older version resulting in this issue. Although I am surprised to see this since they are both within 2.4.x but I have verified this to be the case. I have not gone into details of config parameters etc.

Answer (score 1):

It can't start because it's already running (and the pid file somehow doesn't reflect that). Kill it yourself, then restart it.

Comment: Yes I know this sorry forgot to include in the details. But I end up with this situation much too often.

Comment: Run it on EL7 instead of EL6 or prior. Then you will have systemd, which is much better at keeping track of processes.

Answer (score 1):

Late but i hope it could help.

In my case it happened just because there was already a zabbix process running in background.

```
> service zabbix-agent status
 * zabbix_agentd is not running
```

But if i check PIDS

```
> pgrep zabbix
   14430
   14431
   14432
```

So kill them manually

```
> pgrep zabbix | xargs kill
```

And just restart and verify the service

```
> service zabbix-agent restart
> service zabbix-agent status
 * zabbix_agentd is running
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with multiple network interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`. As it turned out, Zabbix couldn't listen to `0.0.0.0` but worked fine when listening to `eth0`'s address. Hope this helps someone else having this problem for the same reason.

```
ListenIP=111.222.111.222
```